# sql redshift casewhen date = current month

Tags: sql, date

I'm trying to write a case when the month and year within date field (move_in_month) is equal to the current month/year. I wrote:

```
  when date_part(m,temp.move_in_month) = date_part(m,getdate()) and date_part(y,temp.move_in_month) = date_part(y,getdate()) and engagement_rate <= .4 then 'Flag' 
  else 'No Flag' end as low_use_yn
```

and have also tried several other variations, but it's not working. Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ended up with:

```
  case
      when date_trunc('month', temp.move_in_month) = date_trunc('month',current_date)
        and date_trunc('year', temp.move_in_month) = date_trunc('year',current_date)
        and engagement_rate <= .4 then 'Flag'
      else 'No Flag' end as low_use_yn
```

Solution found!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `date_trunc()`:

```
date_trunc('month', temp.move_in_month) = date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE)
```

Redshift doesn't support indexes, but if `move_in_month` is a partitioning key, then this might be safer:

```
temp.move_in_month >= date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) and
temp.move_in_month < date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '1 month'
```

Comment: Ok, I have 
      `case
          when date_trunc('month', temp.move_in_month) = date_trunc('month',now())
            and date_trunc('year', temp.move_in_month) = date_trunc('year',now())
            and engagement_rate <= .4 then 'Flag'
          else 'No Flag' end as low_use_yn`

and am getting

Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;

Comment: @aks85 . . . Huh?  Why are you using `date_trunc()` on both the year and the month?  The real problem is `now()`, the more standard `CURRENT_DATE` is more appropriate.

Comment: yep, switched it to current_date --- all fixed thanks!